# RoR: collection_select not setting the value in the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3 and I am having a problem. My `collection_select` is not populating the field in the DB. This is what my view looks like: (some html was removed)

```
f.label "Company Name"
@c = Company.all
collection_select(:Company , :company_id, @c, :id , :companyName, {:prompt => true})   
f.submit
```

The drop down list has the correct values, but when I submit it, this is what my `params` looks like: `"Company"=>{"company_id"=>"2"}`. I don't have a field called `company`, but I do have a field called `company_id` and a table called `company`. Is my syntax correct?

```
Processing by RecordsController#create as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"WLzwCoZFCUhyH9ZqYWYLmaQwyleB3JLoTnb4lhftKzc=", "record"=>{"title"=>"test", "Company"=>{"company_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Create record"}

AREL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "records" ("company_id", "title", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (NULL, 'test','2011-05-17 05:01:38.905717', '2011-05-17 05:01:38.905717')
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/Records/7
Completed 302 Found in 150ms
```

Comment: Not sure this helps but I want to clear one thing up. In Rails you'll have a top level param that holds the params for the related model object. So the "Company" that points to the actual params is the thing to send to update_attributes, or new or whatever you're calling to affect the model in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
# in controller
@companies = Company.all

collection_select @record, :company_id, @companies, :id, :companyName
```

or

```
form_for @record do |f|
  = f.collection_select :company_id, @companies, :id, :companyName
```