# saving selection from collection_select and passing to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a dropdownmenu which populates from the database. I'm using the following code to do it:-

```
<%= collection_select(:abc, :SkillSetName, @technologies, :id, :Topic) %>
```

I have no idea what :abc and :SkillSetName are doing here. I just know that the drop down is being populated with :Topic from my @technologies variable. I want to save the selection made by the user from the drop down menu and send it to the next controller action. I don't want to use f.collection_select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what `:abc` and `:SkillSetName` are, how are we supposed to know?

Anyway, the user's selection will be in:

```
params[:abc][:SkillSetName]
```

If you want to understand what you are doing, have a look at the API for [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select).

Comment: In that case you have to change `:id` to `:Topic`. Have you looked at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select yet?

Comment: @Mischa, this was exactly what I was looking for. I could see that in my form it was grabbing the project_id like this `"project"=>{"project_id"=>"2"}, ...` but I didn't know how to access the project_id hash. Makes perfect sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer - [RoR: collection_select not setting the value in the DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026481/ror-collection-select-not-setting-the-value-in-the-db/6030478#6030478)

Answer (score 0):

:abc stand for your object and :SkillSetName stand for your method.

when you want to save its value you can get it using `params[:abc][:SkillSetName]`